# Sort by Today, Yesterday, and All posts before yesterday - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

So here's my code:

```
<div id="content" role="main">

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <div class="page-content rich-content">

            <?php
                // Recently Updated

                $args = array(                      
                    'view' => 'grid-mini',
                    'title' => __('Recently Added', 'dp'),
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
                    'posts_per_page' => 999,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                );
                dp_section_box($args);
            ?>

        </div>

    </div><!--end .hentry-->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I would like to sort the query into different sections.

Each section will be a page, so I really don't need to have the args put into one file.

I am asking how is it possible to sort them by: Today, Yesterday, and all Posts before yesterday!

I have been searching online for over 5 hours now, no luck :)

Comment: The issue is not to sort really but to retrieve posts based on those criteria? Have you tried PHP's `array_filter` function? I would think you can pass your posts into an array and then use `array_filter` with a custom callback function to retrieve only posts from those desired dates?

Comment: Thanks Cerd for the reply, I tried array_filter, but keeps on giving me black data .. I think my code is messed up :) .. Got any other ideas?